# Time complexity of power()

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, time-complexity

I implemented this function `power()` which takes two arguments `a` and `b` and computes a<sup>b</sup>.

```
typedef long long int LL;

LL power(int a,int b)
{
   int i = 1;
   LL pow = 1; 
   for( ; i <= b ; ++i )
     pow *= a;
   return pow;
}
```

Given : a<sup>b</sup> falls in the range of `long long int`. 
Problem : How to reduce the time complexity of my algorithm?

Comment: Given an arbitrary degree of precision, it's possible to compute exponentation in constant time.

Comment: @Crashworks only if the exponent is bounded by a constant, right?

Comment: @vidstige Yes, I assume both base and exponent are stored in a finite-length register.

Comment: @Crashworks: this homework assignment is after an algorithm with better complexity, though, not a semantic argument about whether it's ever appropriate to apply complexity analysis to programs with a finite upper bound on the size of the input.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Hush, you're spoiling a perfectly good snipe hunt!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Exponentiation by Squaring.

[image]

A non-recursive implementation

```
LL power(int a, int b)
{
  LL pow = 1;
  while ( b ) 
  {
         if ( b & 1 ) 
         {
           pow = pow * a;
           --b;
         }
         a = a*a;
         b = b/2;
  }
  return pow;
}
```

This algorithm requires **log<sub>2</sub>b** squarings and at most **log<sub>2</sub>b** multiplications.

The running time is **O(log b)**

---

Answer (score 7):

Use [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Answer (score 5):

Exponentiation by squaring does not give the minimal number of multiplications in all cases.  Look for "addition chains", "Brauer chains", "Hansen chains", and "Scholz conjecture".

Comment: This answer would have been much more useful had it links to reading on those particular algorithms.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest: Use the pow() function if you really need a faster function (with long double ) or think about your homework for yourself.

For arbitrary precision: See the GMP lib
http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Exponentiation.html#Integer-Exponentiation

Answer (score 3):

Use exponentiation by squares. That is if we need a^b, we check if b is even, if b is even, we find `(a^2)^(b/2)`, else we find `a*((a^2)^(b/2))`. This may not be the best algorithm, but it is better than the linear algorithm.

```
int Power(int a, int b)
{
    if (b>0)
    {
       if (b==0)
          return 1;
       if (a==0)
          return 0;
       if (b%2==0) {
          return Power(a*a, b/2);
       }
       else if (b%2==1)
       {
        return a*Power(a*a,b/2);
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the recursive implementation of Java code
for 2 to the power of n with O(log n) complexity using [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

```
int ans=1;
public int myTwoPower(int n){
    if(n<=0)
        return 1;

    if(n%2 !=0){            
        return myTwoPower(n-1)*2;
    }
    else{
        ans = myTwoPower(n/2);
        return ans * ans;
    }
}
```

[image]