# Do power functions run in constant time?

Tags: math, time-complexity, bezier

When I use power functions like Math.Pow(double x, double y) in C# or the math.h pow-function in C++ do these run in constant time?

The reason I am asking is because I want to know if a "precalculated" bézier-function on the form (1-t)^n*p0 + ... + t^(n) * pN could run in linear time which could then be faster than an implementation of De Casteljaus algorithm taking control points and t as parameters.

Comment: You can find some excellent information in this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231096/time-complexity-of-power

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that these methods use iteration based processing to get the result, and only stop when the difference between the value of two iterations fall bellow a given error-constant.

There are iterative methods that converge very fastly to the result of a power operation... so I think they are near constant time.

This question has a lot of great explanations:
[How is Math.Pow() implemented in .NET Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870442/how-is-math-pow-implemented-in-net-framework)

**EDIT**

I have found a lot of good meterial to work with in http://math.stackexchange.com.

- [Fastest way to calculate e^x upto arbitrary number of decimals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18445/fastest-way-to-calculate-ex-upto-arbitrary-number-of-decimals)
- [How to calculate e^x with a standard calculator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55830/how-to-calculate-ex-with-a-standard-calculator)
- [How can I calculate non-integer exponents?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62203/how-can-i-calculate-non-integer-exponents)
- [Numerically estimate a^b](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133690/numerically-estimate-ab)
- [Approximation of e^(−x)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71357/approximation-of-e-x)

This one is very interesting, as it explains a way of calculating exponentiation using human language:

- [How to Use a Fixed Point to Calculate an Exponentiation](http://www.ehow.com/how_6563047_use-fixed-point-calculate-exponentiation.html)

**Thoughts**

I'm not a math genius, but as far as I can see, the time it takes does not depend a lot on the values you choose, but on the number of precise digits you want. What I'm trying to say is that it depends on the arguments, but there is a maximum.

Also, to support this theory, take a look at this algorithm (implemented by Sun): http://pastebin.com/LDjS5mAR. There is no loops, only ifs. I think that it is because the guys who implemented it, chose a fixed precision they wanted... and then expanded all the iterations needed to guarantee that precision.

For instance, a loop of invariant number of iterations can be easyly expanded like this:

```
for (int it = 0; it < 5; it++)
    a *= a;
```

Is the same as:

```
a *= a; a *= a; a *= a; a *= a; a *= a;
```

Comment: Ahh thanks that was a very good link! Great stuff! Do you have any reference to mentioned fast iterative methods? And do their speed depend on the power?

Comment: I could not find the specific way it was implemented... they say it was bought from Intel. I'll try to find some information about iterative power methods, and post it here.