# What is the time complexity to calculate 2^5000?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

**What is the time complexity to calculate 2^5000** ?

I approached it, by recursion but then it leads to O(N) where N = power of a number. Is there any way to reduce this time complexity ?

Comment: 2^5000 is a constant, not an algorithm. Time complexity relates algorithms with some set of parameters, typically just 'n', with n tending to infinity. It makes no sense to ask for n=5000. You also need to specify the algorithm: a lookup table? shifting 1 left n times? some other calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are interested in general approach, not only in this given example.

You can calculate N-th integer power using Log(N) operations with [exponentiation by squaring approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

But note that number `2^N` consists of about N binary digits (bits) and simple writing in memory is O(N) operation

Comment: Thanks for the link. It covers all aspects .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231096/time-complexity-of-power. Is is saying thar time complexity is O(log b)

Comment: "simple writing in memory is O(N) operation: - Can you elaborate this.

Comment: Yes, I said the same.

Comment: But, i didn't understand the last line. plz elaborate

Comment: Theoretic analysis might consider that numbers are suitable in machine words (2-4-8 bytes). Reading and writing such number is O(1) operation. But long numbers occupy many bytes (O(N) for N-th power).

Comment: It means that to store the result of this computation requires O(N), right ?

Comment: Yes, it does. Moreover, the last long-number multiplication will take O(NlogN) time. Against - theoretic analysis might omit such ' dirty details'....

Comment: Thanks, i got it now !!

Comment: `note that number 2^N consists of about N binary digits (bits) and simple writing in memory is O(N) operation` - even worse: if you want that number in decimal, you may be better off to compute in a decimal-oriented number representation to begin with - and repeatedly multiplying (table lookup?) may be fastest.